# Convert a php script to codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3

Please i am working on a project and need to generate pincode per request. This is the script i have for php but i need to implement codeigniter 3. Also please can i set it in such a way that if i want 10 pin i input 10 and generate 10 into the database and if want 50 i input 50. i am new to codeigniter 3 and i have read the tutorials but doesnt seems to help on this.
Here is my code on php

Please i want to be able to generate base on the number i want per request.

```html
 <?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","hadassa","root", "")
            or die("Cannot connect"); 
$digits = 5;
function gen_ran($digits) {
$n = "";
  for ($x = 1; $x <= $digits; $x++) {
  $n.=mt_rand(0,9);
  }
return $n;
}
function gen_ran2($digits)
{
    $n2 = "";
    for($a=1; $a<=$digits; $a++)
    {
        $n2 .=mt_rand(0,9);
    }
    return $n2;
}  
for($a=1; $a<=20; $a++)
{
    $codes =  gen_ran($digits) . gen_ran2($digits);

    $query = "INSERT INTO pin (pin)
                VALUES ('$codes')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)
            or die("Error");
    if($result)
echo"$codes<br>"; 

}
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("PIN Generated Successfully");
      window.location = "#";
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

codeignater use the MVC So
create a controller in controller folder to write logic

create a model in models folder for write database code

in the viewer, folder create a view for the user view code

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K71j-rWXejk&index=2&list=PLUpnKy5Si8zDouvZiUMHwSSyVrowJmH22

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOZqRgOgSu4

Comment: helpful but i need to just generate random numbers and store them to database